# Ubuntu 19.10: clikcing on "Show Applications" will block computer

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.10, search

I installed recently 19.10, and after three weeks, got a problem with the '*Show Applications*' icon on the bottom left: if I click on it, it won't show any of the applications, and almost freezes (see pic below). I particular, I won't be able to do any of:

- Escape from it: <kbd>Esc</kbd> won't work.
- Type something in it: mouse works but clicking on the field won't print any letter.
- Switch to another app: interestingly, I can start other Programs, but even there, I can't type anything.

Only solution is to reboot. The problem appears every time I click on the icon of 'Show Applications'.

Any idea what I can do to troubleshoot? Is it stuck searching for programs? What's the name of that Show Applications if I search with `top`? Is it a part of Nautilus, GNOME etc.?

[image]

Comment: It's a part of the GNOME Shell. What happens if you press <Super><A> instead of clicking the 'Show Applications' icon? (<Super> is usually the key with the Windows logo)

Comment: @pomsky, unfortunately, exactly the same behaviour happens:-(